# Spring Boot Embedded Keycloak server throwing NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, keycloak

I've been playing around with spring boot and stumbled onto a guide about embedding Keycloak into a Spring Application, I thought this would a fun little project so I have been following [This guide](https://www.baeldung.com/keycloak-embedded-in-spring-boot-app).

I have implemented everything and the project is building, but crashing at start. This is the error:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.infinispan.configuration.global.GlobalJmxStatisticsConfigurationBuilder org.infinispan.configuration.global.GlobalConfigurationBuilder.globalJmxStatistics()'`

I've searched around for a bit and haven't had much luck. I've tried messing around with the dependencies to see if I am missing something, I have also verified that I can import `org.infinispan.configuration.global.GlobalConfigurationBuilder;` which is available, so could be version conflicts? Any help would be appreciated.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.geolaw</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloaktest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>keycloaktest</name>
    <description></description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.2.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
            <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>
            <version>${infinispan.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jgroups</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jgroups</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-dependencies-server-all</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> „*…so could be version conflicts?…*“

That is it, essentially. It all starts with…

```xml
…
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
…
```

You upgrading from [*Baeldung's original 2.2.6.RELEASE*](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/oauth-rest/oauth-authorization-server/pom.xml#L14) of Spring Boot to *2.3.4.RELEASE*, caused a whole cascading domino affect of incompatible dependencies.

Unless you desperately need to be on *2.3.4*, my advice is to just roll back to *2.2.6.RELEASE*. Or else you'll need a machete as long as your arm to hack your way through the tangled morass of incompatible dependencies that results from that upgrade.

I've pushed [*this working demo*](https://github.com/deduper/geolaw.embedded.keycloak) to confirm that *2.2.6.RELEASE* at least works with JDK 15.

Comment: You're a legend! Thanks for taking the time to answer and put a demo up. Truth be told I was using what ever default version the spring initializer provided. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
The maximum versions i have updated in my pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>15</java.version>

    <keycloak.version>11.0.3</keycloak.version>

    <!-- these should be updated together with Keycloak -->
    <!-- check keycloak-dependencies-server-all effective pom -->
    <infinispan.version>10.1.8.Final</infinispan.version>
    <resteasy.version>3.12.1.Final</resteasy.version>
</properties>
```

I have tried to update the keycloak to any versions more than 11.0.4 version and the spring boot more than 2.3.12.RELEASE but it's impossible - incompatible versions. Maybe who knowns how to update?